# How can i get image file from google drive programatically on android?

Tags: android

Hello I am opening simple intent for getting image files from device:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_IMAGE_FIRST);
```

and it works fine, until i select image from the device, gallery or sdcard, but it offers me google drive as well and if i select image from there it stops the whole application.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=41, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc=1;doc=3310 flg=0x1 }} to activity
```

how can i get images (file) from google drive?

After I get back image I get the path to file, and then i upload it with retrofit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you cannot be using ACTION_GET_CONTENT in Google Drive. It was wrongly supported by Google in the older version. But latest version of Drive (1.1.470.15) the intents have been disabled and ACTION_GET_CONTENT will not throw up Drive as an option.